# Disable a sequence container in SSIS using SQL query?

Tags: ssis

Suppose I have a SSIS package which is having almost 20 sequence containers and while running the job, a few sequence container got completed successfully but a few fail. So, here I want an automated SQL query to disable the completed sequence container and enable the failed sequence container so that if I run the package again, then it will run only failed sequence container.

Is there any chance to disable the completed sequence container and run the failed one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CHECKPOINT file feature in SSIS to automatically run only the failed containers in the control flow task. It is available out of the box in SSIS. You can configure it in the package.

[Read more on Checkpoint usage](https://www.sqlshack.com/using-checkpoint-in-ssis-package-to-restart-package-execution/) & [Restart packages using checkpoint on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/restart-packages-by-using-checkpoints?view=sql-server-ver15)

[image: Checkpoint File setting]

Comment: Thank you Venkataraman R.  Yes we can use Checkpoint for this. But i wanted to disable the Sequence container using SQL query.

Comment: mark this as answer. so, it will be helpful for others in future.

Comment: I think its better to use CHECKPOINT feature. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I detest checkpoints. They don't work within the context of a loop and maybe it's just my bad luck, but I have far too often experienced a corruption of the checkpoint file

I always advise clients to design their ETL solutions with restartability in mind. At some point, the process will fail and you know it's going to be in the middle of something crucial so remove the "thinking" aspect of getting it restarted. Don't make it depend on someone running a script to clean up half committed loads, etc. But that's a different question...

Every object in your control flow will support a property called `Disable`. When you run a package, you can deactivate tasks via the /SET command. Given the following example, each sequence container has a Script Task that does nothing but [fires an information event](https://billfellows.blogspot.com/2016/04/biml-script-task-test-for-echo.html)

[image]

When I run that from the command line,

```
C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\SO_Trash\SO_Trash>dtexec /file SO_61477591.dtsx /rep i
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 14.0.3238.1 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

Started:  10:45:43 AM
Info: 2020-04-28 10:45:43.71
   Code: 0x00000000
   Source: SCR0 SCR Echo Back
   Description: System::ParentContainerGUID : {3910E325-F3D0-4EC6-96FD-5E125FEC0ED2}
End Info
Info: 2020-04-28 10:45:43.74
   Code: 0x00000000
   Source: SCR1 SCR Echo Back
   Description: System::ParentContainerGUID : {08bf88d5-71c3-4105-824e-bb8b1e942b24}
End Info
Info: 2020-04-28 10:45:43.77
   Code: 0x00000000
   Source: SCR2 SCR Echo Back
   Description: System::ParentContainerGUID : {59823604-1caf-4a90-9303-45d55126d8b3}
End Info
Info: 2020-04-28 10:45:43.80
   Code: 0x00000000
   Source: SCR3 SCR Echo Back
   Description: System::ParentContainerGUID : {977567f1-6bcf-4c84-909e-eb18ba17165d}
End Info
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
Started:  10:45:43 AM
Finished: 10:45:43 AM
Elapsed:  0.609 seconds
```

By specifying the path to the executable, I can set the property disable property like `/set \Package\SEQC1.Properties[Disable];"True"` where SEQC1 is the case sensitive name of the object I want to disable

```
C:\Users\bfellows\source\repos\SO_Trash\SO_Trash>dtexec /file .\SO_61477591.dtsx /rep i /set \Package\SEQC1.Properties[Disable];"True"
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 14.0.3238.1 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

Started:  10:45:50 AM
Info: 2020-04-28 10:45:50.62
   Code: 0x00000000
   Source: SCR0 SCR Echo Back
   Description: System::ParentContainerGUID : {3910E325-F3D0-4EC6-96FD-5E125FEC0ED2}
End Info
Info: 2020-04-28 10:45:50.66
   Code: 0x00000000
   Source: SCR2 SCR Echo Back
   Description: System::ParentContainerGUID : {59823604-1caf-4a90-9303-45d55126d8b3}
End Info
Info: 2020-04-28 10:45:50.69
   Code: 0x00000000
   Source: SCR3 SCR Echo Back
   Description: System::ParentContainerGUID : {977567f1-6bcf-4c84-909e-eb18ba17165d}
End Info
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_SUCCESS (0).
Started:  10:45:50 AM
Finished: 10:45:50 AM
Elapsed:  0.609 seconds
```

Notice that SCR1 is no longer in the output due to the SET command disabling it.

Knowing how to disable tasks, you could leave the package as-is and modify your start to be text generated from SQL Queries (give me all the tasks that have completed and build the correct /SET statements)

A better approach that would require modification to the existing package would be have an Execute SQL Task(s) that runs at the start of the package and it sets Boolean SSIS variables with an indicator of whether the Task should be disabled. And then modify each object to have an expression on the Disable property that is the new SSIS variable.

Personally, my approach is to make many SSIS packages. Each package is a unit of work (load sales table). When a package fires, it records that execution has begun. When it completes successfully, it records that it has completed (as well has how many rows inserted/updated/deleted)

I then have a orchestrator package that queries the list of known packages and identifies any package that has not run successfully. It then uses a foreach loop with an Execute package task to then start running the child processes.

[image]

An advantage to my approach is that, assuming no dependencies between task 1 and 3, I could have two copies of this running - one "stack" handles the package 0 and 2, while a different stack handles 1 and 3. One of the advantages of SSIS is that it makes it trivial to parallelize your workload.

Comment: one doubt. how does the orchestrator package know, which package was successful or failure.

Comment: `When a package fires, it records that execution has begun. When it completes successfully, it records that it has completed` Imagine a table with package name, start date and stop date and a surrogate key/identity column. The first task is an Execute SQL Task that populates package name and start time and returns the surrogate key to the package. The final task is an Execute SQL Task that updates the existing record with a stop date. The orchestrator then queries the table looking for packages with no end time (errored out) or no entry (never started).

Comment: Got it. Thanks for clarifying. I think we can also see historical status of package executions in `SSISDB.CATALOG.executions` and see the list of child packages failed and accordingly run the failed packages.