# Enable / disable the Sequence Container in SSIS using SQL query. Eg. Update table set property_value=1 where id='';

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

Can anyone tell me which table SSIS package details stores in SQL Server? And how can we set the property values using SQL Query rather than manually updating in SSIS package? I don't want to update from SSIS package, I wanted to update the SSIS sequence container details using SQL query. Is it possible?

Here I am trying to update a sequence container from back-end.

Eg:

```
update table set property_value=1
where id='{3a76961d-3be9-47d2-a8f0-2d547adbef63}';
```

Comment: No that's not possible. Why are you asking this question over and over again? You already marked it as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61477591/disable-a-sequence-container-in-ssis-using-sql-query

Comment: You can't edit an SSIS package in place inside the SSISDB (well you can but it's almost impossible to do anything meaningful). The way this is done is you make your SSIS package smart so that it looks up a control table (that you need to create) to work out which sequence containers it needs to disable or not disable before it starts running. You need to embed the logic on your package to look up table values at runtime.

Comment: Thanks Nick, I think it makes sense.